# Plagiarism system using google

Tags: google-custom-search, plagiarism-detection

I am creating an Arabic plagiarism detector. I need to check the paper  against the web, I am using Google custom search to retrieve results. but Google offers limited number of queries ( 100 per day for free , or you have to purchase max of 10000 per day which is not enough ) .
I wonder if there are any ways to search the web for certain content. may be Google for business or other search engine. 
Or should create my own crawler?
I need a solution to this.
any ideas?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that Google doesn't have _some_ type of business licensing arrangement that would fit this scenario. Off-topic here, though.

Comment: I think Google has some business solution, but I don't know where to go. I can't reach google support office.

Comment: You can integrate with third-party plagiarism service and implement your own application logic. I can recommend you using REST service called Copyleaks (more info in https://api.copyleaks.com website). They also have open source code published on GitHub.